# My android app crashes using SAX parser in android 4.1

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

Hello everyone I tried to parse the rss feed of nasa website " image of the day" to my app but every time I start the app it crashes and stops working. I'm complitelyconfused.
API level of my test device is 16
Thanks inadvance

MainActivity code:

```
public class NasaImageViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nasa_image_view);
        xmlHandler handler = new xmlHandler();
        handler.processFeed();
        resetScreen(handler.getTitle(), handler.getDate(), handler.getDescription(), handler.getImage());
    }

    public void resetScreen (String titleSTR , String dateSTR , StringBuffer describe, Bitmap bm){
        TextView title =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(titleSTR);
        TextView date =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pubDate);
        date.setText(dateSTR);
        TextView describtion =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        describtion.setText(describe);
         ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

Sax parser code:

```
enter code here class xmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
Boolean onItem = false, onEnclosure = false, onTitle = false, onPubDate = false , onDescription = false;
String title = null, date = null, url = "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/lg_image_of_the_day.rss";
Bitmap image = null;
StringBuffer description = new StringBuffer();

public void processFeed(){
    try{
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        reader.parse(new InputSource(is));
    }catch (Exception e){}
}

public Bitmap getBitmap (String url){
    try{
        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        input.close();
        return image;
    }catch(IOException e){return null;}
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("item")) 
        onItem = true;
    else if (onItem){
        if (localName.equals("enclosure")) onEnclosure = true;
        else onEnclosure = false;
        if (localName.equals("title")) onPubDate = true;
        else onPubDate = false;
        if (localName.equals("pubDate")) onPubDate = true;
        else onPubDate = false;
        if (localName.equals("description")) onDescription = true;
        else onDescription = false;
    }
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    String chars =(String) new String(ch).subSequence(start, start+length);
    if (onEnclosure && image == null) { image = getBitmap(chars); }
    if (onTitle && title == null) { title = chars; }
    if (onDescription) { description.append(chars); }
    if (onPubDate && date == null) { date = chars; }
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
}

public Bitmap getImage() { return image; }
public String getTitle() { return title; }
public StringBuffer getDescription() { return description; }
public String getDate() { return date; }

}
```